# #Render partial with a model in Layout View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, model, partial-views

I have a MVC project where I want to render my menu using Model.

I declare the menu contents at the `Session_Start` event in Global.asax.cs and using break point i knew that it is filling out correctly.

I cannot simply use `@Html.Partial("_Menu")` inside my `_Layout.cshtml`

And if I do `@Html.Partial("_Menu", Model.Something)`, I get a

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

error on the Model.

Answer (score 2):

First off I would recommend against the session object, but since you're using it then in the Initialize method (override) of a common controller that **ALL** controllers inherit from you'll grab the menu data from the session, and push it into the viewbag. Then in the _Layout you can retrieve the object from the viewbag (

```
var navigationItems = ViewBag.NavigationItems as NavigationViewModel;
```

) as field and use that object anywhere by passing it or a property of it to a partial for rendering (

```
@Html.Partial("_Navigation", navigationItems)
```

).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Razor - **Section** for this:

Inside _Layout.cshtml:

```
<div id=”menu”> 
@RenderSection("Menu", required:false)
</div>
```

& On the pages (Eg. Index.cshtml) you want Menu:

```
@section Menu 
{
 @Html.Partial("_Menu", Model.Something)
}
```

Comment: getting null reference exception in this also

Answer (score 0):

Provide more details:

- Why you are using `Session_Start`?
- How you filling model `Model.Something`?

The simplest way for creating dynamic menu is `@Html.RenderAction`.

Comment: Session start to get the values of menu from database at the start.
In that I am filling the Model.Something .
And then rendering the partial view at the _layout.cshtml view.

how can i use @Html.RenderAction in the current scenario?

Comment: @Abhishek You can use `RenderAction` for all your logic, this is like `Partial`, but you can get any data from action: use caching, access database and etc.

Comment: But how can i pass my model to it.
That also gives null reference exception.

Comment: @Abhishek You can set `routeValues` and then return partial result from action. [RenderAction Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703490%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)